# AJAXy control buttons on user profile page can break

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

EDIT: not sure of the etiquette but based on the comments I opened this on meta.stackoverflow.com as [AJAXy control buttons on user profile page can break](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74544/ajaxy-control-buttons-on-user-profile-page-can-break)

--

In Chrome 8.0.552.224 on Windows 7, I found a bug in which I receive what looks to me like the raw, unformatted output of an ajax call vs having that output incorporated in the page correctly.  I seem to be able to reproduce it at will in Chrome.  I was going to say that Firefox 3.6.13 didn't have the same problem, but I banged on it some more and recreated it there too.

Here's what my page looks like when I follow the steps below:

http://jetmore.org/john/misc/error.png

Here are the steps to reproduce in Chrome:

- Load serverfault.com
- click on my username at the top to load my profile
- scroll down to "Answers" section
- click on any of the "answers" page numbers to to go any page but #1 (so, click "2" or "next")
- click on any of the answers to load that question page in the same tab
- click the back button to return from the question page to the profile page
- scroll back down to the "answers" page numbers again
- click a different page number
- Boom, all the data that should be loaded in the answers section, but in a new page, not incorporated in the profile page.

Steps to reproduce in firefox (this works in Chrome too and is actually a simpler way to reproduce, but I'm leaving the Chrome steps because it's how I found the problem organically which might be useful reference):

- load serverfault.com
- click my username to load profile page
- scroll to answers
- click one of the numbers to go to a different page of answers (2, for instance)
- F5 to reload the page
- scroll back down and click another answers page index number (2 again will work)
- And again, what appears to be the ajax response rather than the page w/ the response incorporated into it.

Comment: I can confirm the firefox version of this bug for Safari on MacOS 10.6.6 as well.

Comment: +1 - also confirmed. Strongly recommend posting this on meta.stackoverflow.com as it will get more visibility there.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, plain ol' bug needed some fixin'.

This will work fine in the next build. Thanks!